# Hide folder in URL but not if there is only domain in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to hide folder 'main' in my URL. So if there is a file like:

my_domain.com/main/something.php

I get:

my_domain.com/something.php

The best solution I have found is:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+main/([^\s]+) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule (?!^main/)^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L,NC]
```

and it works fine but not in the case when in the URL is only 'my_domain.com'.
Then I get "You don't have permission to access /main/ on this server." as the URL is probably changed to 'my_domain.com/main/'

How can I modify it to work only when there is something more than only domain in URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+main/([^\s]+) [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^((?!^main/).+)$ /main/$1 [L,NC]
```